# How can add Photo Frame on my Cameraview for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

hey all,
         please anyone tell me that how can i set Photo frame on capture view in iphone programming. i appreciate your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overlaying a frame on the Camera View and then saving and using the resulting photo (what was captured and the overlay frame)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363402/overlaying-a-frame-on-the-camera-view-and-then-saving-and-using-the-resulting-pho)

Answer (score 1):

Here's are two tutorials with code you can follow...

http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=821
http://blog.blackwhale.at/2009/10/custom-video-overlay-view-on-the-iphone/